# Django: Urls Optional Query Parameters

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

**Urls.py:**

```
app_name = 'main'
urlpatterns = [    
    path('',include(router.urls)), 
    path('player_id=<str:player>%season_id=<str:season>',views.MatchesList.as_view())  
]
```

**Views.py**

```
class MatchesList(generics.ListAPIView):

serializer_class = MatchesSerializer
permissions      = (IsAuthenticated)

def get_queryset(self):
    player = self.kwargs['player']
    season = self.kwargs['season']
    if season is None:
        queryset = Matches.objects.filter(player=player).all()
    else:      
        queryset = Matches.objects.filter(player=player,season=season).all()     
    return queryset
```

Is there any way to request without the parameter 'season'? Something like that:

```
app_name = 'main'
urlpatterns = [    
    path('',include(router.urls)), 
    path('player_id=<str:player>',views.MatchesList.as_view())  
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure. In DRF you can/should use [filtering](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering/) for this.

In `urls.py` you'll have something like this:

```
path('matches/<str:player_id>/', views.MatchesList.as_view())
```

And your URL will look like:

```
https://yourhost.com/matches/42/?season=spring
```

For `season` you'll have to implement a filter (there is a bunch of ways to do it). Filters are optional — if you'll not pass the `?season=something` part of the URL, it just will not be applied.